# C# ignoring letter case for if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this if statement:

```
if (input == 'day')
    Console.Write({0}, dayData);
```

When the user types 'day' it should be so that the console writes the data in that array. It works fine but is there anyway to get it to work if the user types 'DaY' or 'dAy' etc. I know I could do:

```
if (input == 'day' || input == 'dAy' || input == 'DaY')
     Console.WriteLine({0}, dayData);
```

But is there anyway to make it shorter and tidier?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (input.ToLower() == "day") { }
```

If your code is international, you are writing a library, you want a small speed boost, you are doing this in a loop or with large strings, et cetera, use the following:

```
if (input.Equals("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { }
```

Or to use a specific international culture:

```
if (string.Compare(input, "day", true, new CultureInfo("de-DE")) == 0) { }
```

Comment: This worked! Seems simpler and contains less code than the other answers as well. Thank You! :D

Comment: Don't forget to this as the answer if it worked for you

Comment: @JJ85, you're welcome. Juan's is actually more correct (except I think OrdinalIgnoreCase is suggested) if the code is international.

Comment: And do not forget that this approach have the problem that if input is null it will crash.

Comment: @Juan That can be fixed by checking `input != null` before trying `input.toLower`; if this isn't an international application, it would make more sense to use this solution and do a null check

Comment: I have used this quite a lot. Then I've noticed it is not as efficient as it could be: first, the entire string is being converted, then compared. The .Equals function with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase compares and ignores the case in just one step.

Comment: But I think for most cases the answer you provided is good since it is far better memorizable. :-)

Comment: @Matt I forgot to respond. It does sacrifice speed, but increases readability. The speed loss is not something I'd be too worried about unless this is done frequently or on large strings. I also wouldn't use this in a library or international code. I used this the other day on a domestic write-once-then-discard app.

Comment: I agree, thank you for your answer! (and for the updates ;-) )

Answer (score 13):

The string.Equals method allow you to set up configuration on the comparison and you can set it up to ignore case.

```
if (string.Equals(input, "day", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: @Evorlor international. If this code runs in a foreign country, ToLower may not work. I do wish it were a less verbose syntax by default.

Comment: @MillieSmith you mean your code won't work internationally, and juan's will?

Comment: Yeah @Evorlor [character requirement]

Answer (score 2):

The `string.Equals` method allow you could to check the content of the string and ignore the case, for sample:

```
if (input.Equals("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention an array so I'll assume you're entering multiple things simultaneously (like 'day', 'dAy', etc)

```
foreach (var item in input)
{
    if (item.ToLower() == "day")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
        break;
    }
}
```

edit: this would check each item in the array, write to the console, then stop if one was "day".

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```
if(str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    //...
}
```

Second parameter allow you use one of six predefined comparison modes.

Comment: And compared to the accepted answer it has one great advantage: You don't need to convert both str1 and str2 into lowercase yourself! This means, if `str1="HeLLo"` and `str2="hellO"`, it will do the job well and evaluate to `true`. +1 for this :-)